# need help with subject class

Tags: document-classes, journal-publishing

I'm writing a math paper and I have a sample "Journal.tex" that I found online but one function is giving me trouble. In pages about how-to, it seems I need a Mathematics Subject Classification.  I copied and pasted from Journal.tex but it doesn't work in TeXShop on my Mac. Here are the first few lines of my paper.  I can generate a PDF without `\subjclass...` but not with it "in" the document. What am I doing wrong?

```
\begin{document}

\title{On Finding Pythagorean Triples}

\author{Roger M. Ellingson}

%\date{} % Activate to display a given date or no date

\subjclass[2020]{Primary cC40, 14E20; Secondary 46E25, 20C20}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. When posting questions it's important to post complete minimal compilable documents (like the one in my answer). This allows people to see exactly what you are doing, and gives them a document to play with. This will make your questions more understandable and you'll also get answers faster. You can also format code by selecting it and clicking on the `{}` icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `amsart` documentclass,  defines the `\subjclass` macro. If you need a document that includes it, then you should use that class.  If you are preparing a document for a particular journal, and they provide a LaTeX document class for the journal, then you should use that class.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\subjclass[2020]{Primary cC40, 14E20; Secondary 46E25, 20C20}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is the *opposite* of what is being asked.  OP says that `\subjclass` is needed but doesn't work.  `amsart` does provide `\subjclass`; there are a few other journal classes that provide it, but I don't remember which ones.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, reading the question again, I think you're right. I've changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: My starter document contained \documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}    "journal sample" contained \documentclass{amsart}.  When I changed "article" to "amsart", then "\documentclass" worked. Thanks.